# How to make a dropdown menu without editing my html

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Im trying to make a drop down menu, i cant edit my html and i must style it completely in css.
Im working with css3

i have it already styled i just need it to actually drop down.

the share 'li' will be the only thing seen on top of the page, when you hover over this the rest of the list items will drop down. Therefore the share li will now be at the bottom of the drop down. So the order from the top it will be in once you hover over the share li is - Twitter, facebook, google, linkedin and share.

heres my html for the dropdown:

```
<ul id = "dropdown">
<li>Twitter</li>
<li>Facebook</li>
<li>Google+</li>
<li>Linkedin</li>
<li>Share</li>
</ul>
```

so far this is what i have in my css

```
#dropdown ul {
float: left;
}



#dropdown li {
background: white;
padding: 10px;
width: 120px;
list-style-type: none;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
}


#dropdown :nth-child(1) {
background-color: gray;
color: white;
border: 6px solid white;
}

#dropdown :nth-child(2) {
border: 6px solid white;
}

#dropdown :nth-child(3) {
background-color: gray;
color: white;
border: 6px solid white;
}

#dropdown :nth-child(4) {
border: 6px solid white;
}

#dropdown :nth-child(5) {border: 6px solid white;
border-top: 1px solid black;
border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
font-weight: bold;}
```

if anyone could help me out on how to style this to drop down the way i need it too it would be great,
thanks

Comment: Hide all `li` but the “share” one, and on hover over the `ul` you display all of them. For a “drop down” effect that does not affect the rest of the elements on the page, you will want to position the `ul` absolutely. (Btw., your selector `#dropdown ul` doesn’t select anything here, since you don’t have any `ul` within `#dropdown`.)

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over an LI element, you are also hovering over it's container, in this case the ul#dropdown element, so adding the following to the end of your styles should work fine:

```
#dropdown li {
    display: none;
}
#dropdown li:last-child {
    display: block;
}
#dropdown:hover li {
    display: block;
}
```